# Can't insert line break in Ajax outputString

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an Ajax script that outputs both the title and description of certain jobs based on user input. While I can get these displaying without issue, I can't seem to insert a line break between the title and description. I have the following:

```
            outputString = savedData[i].firstName + ". Description: " + savedData[i].cardNumber;

            var paragraph = $("<p />", {
            text: outputString
            });
            $("#data").append(paragraph);
```

I have tried inserting a traditional br line break, as well as, \n and \r\n both in the quotation marks before description which just displays the text of the line break rather than breaking the line, and also outside of the quotation marks which breaks any output. How can I successfully implement a linebreak?
Cheers.

Comment: User `<br/>` to add line break

Comment: Hey @LiamF0 , why dont you wrap it in two div elements and then wrap it in a paragraph element. If that is what you are looking for, please let me know. I could help

Comment: @NabilShahid This just displays inline as text rather than breaking the line.

Comment: _“This just displays inline as text”_ - not surprising, considering that you are assigning it to a property _called_ `text` already. `$("<p />").html(…)` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are providing the outputString string as text, the html `<br/>` is being displayed as text in the string. You should specify it in as html and use `<br/>` for line break:

```
outputString = dataJobs[i].title + ". <br/>Description: " + dataJobs[i].description;

              var paragraph = $("<p />", {
              html: outputString
              });
              $("#data").append(paragraph);
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something small I'd missed. Thank you, I didn't realise the issue with providing the string as text instead of html, that makes a lot of sense! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "jQuery way" should look like this:

```
var $outputString = $( "<span>" + dataJobs[i].title + ".<br>Description: " + dataJobs[i].description + "</span>" );
$( "#data" ).append($outputString.wrap( "<p></p>" ));
```

Comment: This simply breaks and nothing is output.

Comment: Ok, fixed. Try it now.

Comment: Fixed again :))

Answer (score 0):

```
outputString = dataJobs[i].title + ". Description: " + dataJobs[i].description + "<br/>";
```

Comment: This just breaks the output unfortunately.

Comment: I tried your edit, but the line breaks at the end just display in the text, like so:


Legal professionals n.e.c.. Description: Job holders in this group perform a variety of other professional legal occupation not listed.<<//br>br/>

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add a `<br/>` specifically, then you can do the following:

```
// assuming that your dataJobs[i].title and dataJobs[i].description are defined

var paragraph = $("<p />");
paragraph
  .append(dataJobs[i].title + '.')
  .append('<br />')
  .append("Description: " + dataJobs[i].description);

$("#data").append(paragraph);
```

You need to add a `<br/>` in a separate append call, but not as part of a string. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below as the *P* tag has display property set to block by default, so there is no need for using line break. 
Setting *Title* and *Description* in two different *P* tags that will solve your problem

Try the following code.

```
outputString = "<p>Title: "+dataJobs[i].title+"</p><p>description: "+dataJobs[i].description+"</p>";
$("#data").append(outputString);
```